# How to package control file generated by dynamic debug into kernel .deb file

Tags: kernel

I modify linux source code by adding some log using dynamic debug function **dev_dbg**.I want to deploy the Customized kernel to several computers . so I do not want to waste time compiling kernel on each server.

Then i follow the step https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel to build kernel and get .deb file.

however after i install the kernel into a new computer, i found the file **/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control**  do not have the new records i added before.

how can i generate a new control file and pack it into the new kernel .deb file or anyting i can do?

Comment: What .debs did you install? Both linux-image and headers? And you booted to the new kernel, right? Show us the `pr_debug` statement you added. As long as the related module, if it is a module, is loaded,  it should be in the list.